# backdrop-filter: blur() not working

Tags: css

Trying to apply the backdrop-filter to achieve a blur effect on the elements behind another element. However, the browser aren't able to apply this effect. The browser is Chrome.

[The inspector:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMGfX.png)

Any tips in how to get this to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't even mentioned what browser you use!!! Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: What does the tooltip say when you hover over that exclamation point?

Comment: It says "Unknown property name" @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: Well, there you go. I doesn't know what that is.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan: Nothing specific that would help troubleshooting this problem.

Comment: @BoltClock I disagree. When I search for "Unknown property name" I get lots of hits, including [Why I get error Unknown property name in css class?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36748512)

Comment: @Mike McCaughan: That's a red herring. The tooltip doesn't distinguish between features that the browser *refuses* to recognize unless a specific setting is changed, and features that don't actually exist (because they were misspelled or because the author was ahead of themselves).

Comment: You're right @BoltClock, there's no possible way anyone could possibly debug this or do research to solve this on their own. Only your answer will save the day...

Comment: @Mike McCaughan: But you're the one suggesting that there's nothing beyond what the tooltip says: "What does it say?" "Unknown property name" "So it's unknown, end of story." While my telling you that it's a red herring suggests that there is in fact more to it that warrants additional research.

Comment: @BoltClock It's not a red herring. It's exactly the reason the property is not working. From there you can search on `backdrop-filter` and find out why it's not supported and what can be done to enable support. A search on a misspelled property name would also yield information about the misspelling (likely in a "Do you mean <correct spelling>"). Or at least, that's how I've used such warnings myself.

Comment: I know the question might not have been worded well, but why so mean?

https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1

Comment: @Tom Golden: The site had always been mean up until recent events culminating in that blog post shook things up (notice that these comments were left several weeks ago that post). That post outlines some of the motivations behind the meanness. Now that you're looking at past examples of folks being mean, understand that these were in the past, consider that some of us might have realized our mistakes (I can say that I have) since that post was published, and strive to encourage others to be better rather than standing at a distance asking "why so mean?" taking past misconduct out of context.

Comment: @Tom Golden: With that in mind, I deleted my own reply to Alon Eitan, that was clearly uncalled for, but I'm leaving the rest behind as I've been a participant in this thread and moderating them would be a conflict of interest (and my disagreements with Mike McCaughan stand anyway). If you like, you can flag for the remaining comments here to be cleaned up and another moderator will handle it.

Answer (score 9):

`backdrop-filter` is currently guarded by the "Enable experimental Web Platform features" flag in Chrome, prefixed in Safari as `-webkit-backdrop-filter`. It will not work unless the end user has configured that flag.

Answer (score 4):

I found out that **elements with transparent background get incorrectly blurred**. So make sure your page is not transparent. In my case, adding this worked like charm.

```
body {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I spent 10+ hours to find out this. I hoped I have found that answer earlier I gone too far.I read all w3c drafts about the old chromium bugs related to this. Thanks 

Comment: so glad I could help!! this was my first addition to StackOverflow ever <3